# how to vue/html canvas product configurator

Tags: web-applications, html5-canvas, vue.js

I'm  looking for a first approach to create a shoe's configurator.
I ask you if is possible to use vue js to create the model of the shoe (upper, tongue...) and interact with a html canvas where I load and update the images of the shoe component via ajax. After i want to have the possibility to save and export the configuration.

You have some idea for starting that project?

Thank's in advance,

D.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow.

I am sorry to tell you but your question does not follow [stack overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Stack overflow does not exist to do your job. SO exists to help you if you got *stuck* at some bug.

Regarding your problem, you will find better responses at [vuejs gitter](https://gitter.im/vuejs/vue)